# Angularjs directive template = $scope.(some variable from another controller)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angular2-directives

This is part of my AngularJS application

```
  .controller('Littlebear',function($scope) {
        $scope.spread='<h1>this is the</h1> Littlebear spread.'+
        '<img ng-src="src/images/retro.png" alt="picture" ng-click="click()">';
    })
   .directive('spread', function($compile) {
     var templateTemp='<p> try again </p>';
      var directive = {};


      directive.compile = function(element, attributes) {

   var linkFunction = function($scope, element, atttributes) {
       // bind element to data in $scope
       templateTemp=$scope.spread;
       return templateTemp;
   };

   return linkFunction;
   };

directive.restrict = 'E'; /* restrict this directive to elements */
directive.template = templateTemp;
return directive;
    })
```

I would like to set template = $scope.spread inside the directory.

If I console.log the templateTemp inside the linkFunction the value of templateTemp is exacly what I am looking for but ouside of that function is templateTemp='

try again

';

can anyone suggest any solution?

(PS: as you might imagine I am quite new to AngularJS)

Thanks Vincent

Answer (score 0):

In link function you can do something as below.
In link function, I have compiled the desired html and replaced the directive element with the same.

```js
.controller('Littlebear',function($scope) {
        $scope.spread='<h1>this is the</h1> Littlebear spread.'+
        '<img ng-src="src/images/retro.png" alt="picture" ng-click="click()">';
    })
   .directive('spread', function($compile) {
     var templateTemp='<p> try again </p>';
      var directive = {};


      directive.compile = function(element, attributes) {

   var linkFunction = function($scope, element, atttributes) {

    // you can change and compile the html like this
    //element.replaceWith($compile($scope.spread)); //Please Check this line<-----

//Please try this.
 var html =$scope.spread;
        var e =$compile(html)($scope);
        element.replaceWith(e);
    
   };

   return linkFunction;
   };

directive.restrict = 'E'; /* restrict this directive to elements */
directive.template = templateTemp;
return directive;
    })
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I tried but I get this error "Argument 1 of Node.replaceChild is not an object."

Comment: I have edited the answer. Check the code given below comment "//Please try this."  $compile needs scope in second function to execute binding expressions against the given scope like this, $compile(html)($scope) . I think this is the reason for error.